# Handling apostrophes when generating HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am generating radio buttons based on an XML config values. Sometimes they have apostrophes in the text. When manipulating this data in PHP, I seem to lose everything after the apostrophe.  For example:

```
<input type='radio' name='remove[]' value='Government wants to limit employers' communications about unionization'>
```

But when dumping it out after the form POSTs, I get this value:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(35) "Government wants to limit employers"
}
```

Any suggestions on how to preserve the full string? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
<input type="radio" ... value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($array[0], ENT_QUOTES) ?>" ... />
```

It's explicitly intended to allow safe insertion of arbitrary text into html without 'breaking' the html. Note the 'ent_quotes' option. By default htmlspecialchars will only handle `<>"`, but since you're using `'`, you need the option to tell htmlspecialchars to handle those too.

Comment: Thanks for the input Marc. Using `htmlspecialchars` with the `ENT_QUOTES` parameter is preserving my radio value. However, I eventually write this value back in to the XML config. I believe the special characters are making my XML corrupt, as I am getting this error:
`Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML() [simplexmlelement.asxml]: xmlEncodeEntitiesReentrant : input not UTF-8output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x92 0x20 0x76 0x69 `

via this code:
`$old = simplexml_load_file($file);
$bar->title = $_SESSION['title'];
$old->asXML($file);`

Any ideas?

Comment: htmspecialchars() has a parameter to specify character set, see the man page here http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotes in the string: `value='Government wants to limit employers&#39; communications about unionization'`  Escaping it will cause this problem to stop.

PHP does give functions for this, in case your information is in a variable.  Just use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Thanks for the response Kyle, however, my values are dynamic.

Comment: I just edited my answer.  Check out the htmlspecialchars function or the addslashes function.

Comment: That's not the right escaping for HTML. It should be `employers&#39; communications`. Or just use double quotes instead of single ones for that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be just to use double quotes like so:

```
<input type='radio' name='remove[]' value="Government wants to limit employers' communications about unionization">
```

It's pretty much the reason for them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually stick with those 2 easy options, both equally efficient:

1. You can encapsulate one type of quotes in the other type

`$var = " here single quotes ' are encapsulated in double quotes";`
`$var = 'here double quotes " are encapsulated in single quotes';`

1. you can escape quotes by using \

`$var = "just quote some mathematician: \"quot erat demonstrandum\".";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to surround the text:

```
<input type='radio' name='remove[]' value="Government wants to limit employers' communications about unionization">
```

An even better way would be to replace the apostrophes with `&#39;`.

```
<input type='radio' name='remove[]' value='Government wants to limit employers&quot; communications about unionization'>
```

This is a more robust solution in case the text includes double quotes as well. You should replace all `'`s with `&#39;`s and `"`s with `&quot;`s.

This can be easily done using `htmlspecialchars(string $str)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php