# Print special characters via php inside a html element's attribute

Tags: php, html, escaping

Assume `$string = AX èdfdfdèsèdsè'/\"` (actually, `$string` is assigned this value from the DB)

So when I print the following,

```
echo "<option value='". htmlspecialchars($string) ."'>".$string."</option>";
```

I get the output,

```
<option \&quot;'="" value="AX èdfdfdèsèdsè">AX èdfdfdèsèdsè'/\"</option>
```

How can I properly escape this so that I don't create another useless attribute & instead get the same value as in `$string`?

Also, what is the reason Php does not escape `$string` as a whole?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. Output is as expected: `<option value='AX èdfdfdèsèdsè'/\&quot;'>AX èdfdfdèsèdsè'/\"</option>`

Comment: PHP itself wouldn't mangle the initial attribute= syntax. Perhaps look at the raw source, not through developer tools etc. Also use `ENT_QUOTES` to escape the single quote, and `htmlentities()` if you meant to escape the accented letters. And ensure the corrrect charset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling apostrophes when generating HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030611/handling-apostrophes-when-generating-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use htmlspecialchars on the second usage of $string in order to prevent breaking the html with a "<". Inside of the option value quotes it is sufficient to replace the single quotes:

```
echo "<option value='".str_replace("'","&#039;",$string)."'>".htmlspecialchars($string)."</option>";
```

Output is:

```
<option value='AX èdfdfdèsèdsè&#039;/\"'>AX èdfdfdèsèdsè'/\&quot;</option>
```

Comment: usage of `htmlspecialchars()` on the second usage did not matter. It was actually breaking in the first one due to the **single quotes**

Comment: Sure. But it's an advice, because you will get other strings from the DB - and then it might matter...

Answer (score 1):

An alternate answer would be using `htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)` So basically that would be

```
echo "<option value='". htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)."'>".($value)."</option>";
```

It seems that neither `htmlspecialchars($value)` nor `htmlentities($value)` convert single-quotes `'` by default unless explicitly setting the `ENT_QUOTES` flag.

Comment: That last sentence is correct, and [the manual](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) says so...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="', htmlspecialchars($string), '">', htmlspecialchars($string), '</option>';
```

PHP doesn't escape anything unless you tell it to. ;)